# regex capturing multiple statements

Tags: php, regex

so i'm working on a project and i'm converting `@misterFoo` to `@[:1234]`(his userid).

This all works and i'm happy but i'll also want to revert this.

I've already figured out the regexp to capture `@[:1234]` but when there's a second occurrence like in this string:

```
"Joo @[:1234] my buddy @[:5678] want's his money back"
```

I can only get `@[:1234]` with my regexp 
`/(@\[:[0-9]])/` i'm probably missing a multiple words or numbers boundary like `+` does or `\b` can someone explain what I need?

someone gave the correct answer in the comments which was in this regex: 
https://regex101.com/r/lL9lB4/1

now i'm facing the trouble of how do i get `1234` out of `@[:1234]`

Comment: Which engine are you using? There should be a replace globally type command.

Comment: Check whether your engine supports `g` (global) flag. `/... /g`

Comment: Check this out. https://regex101.com/r/lL9lB4/1

Comment: i'm using php @BoristheSpider

Comment: Then tag it as such!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed here are the functions I made to solve it:

this is the function that converts the usernames in a string into @[:id] for database

```
public function replaceUsernames($text){
    $pattern = '/@\w+\b/'; 
    preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);
    $sql = $this->db->prepare("
        SELECT `id` 
        FROM `users` u 
        WHERE `username` = :username LIMIT 1
    ");

    foreach($matches[0] as $value){
        $value = str_replace('@','',$value);

        $sql->execute(
            array(
                'username' => $value
            )
        );

        if($sql->rowCount() > 0){
            $user = $sql->fetchObject();
            $text = str_replace($value,'[:'.$user->id.']',$text);
        }
    }
    return($text);
}
```

And this is the reverse function for grabbing data from my db:

```
public function replaceUserids($text){
    $pattern = '/(@\[:[0-9]+\])/'; 
    preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);
    $sql = $this->db->prepare("
        SELECT `username` 
        FROM `users` u 
        WHERE `id` = :id LIMIT 1
    ");

    foreach($matches[0] as $value){

        preg_match('/[0-9]/',$value, $match);
        $id = $match[0];
        $sql->execute(
            array(
                'id' => $id
            )
        );
        if($sql->rowCount() > 0){
            $user = $sql->fetchObject();
            $text = str_replace($value, '@'.$user->username,$text);
        }
    }

    return($text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the pattern which matches digits inside a capturing group.

```
@\[:([0-9]+)\]
```

Grab the string you want from group index 1.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lL9lB4/2)

**OR**

```
@\[:\K[0-9]+(?=\])
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lL9lB4/3)

```
$re = "/@\\[:\\K[0-9]+(?=\\])/";
$str = "Joo @[:1234] my buddy @[:5678] want's his money back";
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) ?